# Bootable USB disk for Ubuntu from Mac; which partition type (APM/MBR/GPT) to choose?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I want to make a bootable USB disk for installing Ubuntu from Mac. When I format the USB disk from terminal, i use

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ KINGSTON GPTFormat /dev/disk1
```

But there are other available options for the partition, like **APMFormat** and **MBRformat**. So which should work for Ubuntu?

I did some search, here's a [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3905667) that discusses these three formats. Here's a quote:

> But if you want to boot OS X (intel) from it, then you need GPT
>
> If you want to boot OS X (PPC) from it, then you need APT
>
> If you want to boot Linux, Windows, BSD, or other OS that boots from the BIOS then you need MBR.

I'm a little confused here; any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: You don't need to format it, instead just use the `dd` command to write the ISO to the USB.  Something like `dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/disk#` (use `diskutil list` to write it to the correct device, otherwise you could corrupt your main HDD or another drive if you type it incorrectly.